# How to set default radio option when using only a div that is replicated with *ngFor in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

In my form I have two radio option for gender. I want to set the default radio on "masculin". I have only one input of type radio who is rendered two times with *ngFor. *ngFor is looping throw an array that contains the two gender.

Other similar questions are using two input radio. But my code use only one input radio with the two values from the array.

.html:

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
            <label>
                <input 
                type="radio" 
                name="gender"
                >
                {{ gender }}
            </label>
</div>
```

.ts :

```
genders = ['masculin', 'feminin'];
```

Comment: You’ll need to set the value as well so [value] = “gender” and then you can use [checked]=“gender===‘masculin’” to set the default

Comment: MikeOne, it's working! Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Enjoy building!

Comment: Thank you bro! I'm new to programming but I really enjoy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The Template Driven approach for using Forms in Angular:

"You’ll need to set the value as well so [value] = “gender” and then you can use [checked]=“gender===‘masculin’” to set the default:" ( Tks to MikeOne )

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
            <label>
                <input 
                type="radio" 
                name="gender"
                [value]="gender"
                [checked]="gender === 'masculin'"
                >
                {{ gender }}
           </label>
```

2. The Reactive Form approach for using Forms in Angular:

.html:

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let gender of genders">
            <label>
                <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    formControlName="gender"
                    [value]="gender" 
                />{{ gender }}
            </label>
</div>
```

In the .ts file, where we define the Reactive Form, we set the first argument of
FormControl class, with the value we want to pass to the radio button, and that's become the default value.

Note:
FormControl() takes 3 param, 1- the initial value, 2- the validator/s, 3- potentional asyncronise validators

.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
      'username': new FormControl(null),
      'lastname': new FormControl(null),
      'firstname': new FormControl(null),
      'age': new FormControl(null),
      'gender': new FormControl('masculin'),
      'email': new FormControl(null),
      'password': new FormControl(null),

    });
  }
```